# WinAPI call to DeviceCapabilities(DC_ENUMRESOLUTIONS) for Epson P50 always report error

Tags: winapi, printing, epson

I'm faced some strange behaviour - it seems it is impossible to enum resolutions for Epson ink printers in Windows.
in particular this code always reports error:

```
int r, err;
char szBuffer[0x4000];
String prnName = "EPSON P50 Series";
String portName = "USB002";

r = DeviceCapabilities(prnName.c_str(), portName.c_str(), DC_ENUMRESOLUTIONS, NULL, NULL);
err = GetLastError();
printf("\n 1.DevCap.result = %d, err = %d", r, err);

r = DeviceCapabilities(prnName.c_str(), portName.c_str(), DC_ENUMRESOLUTIONS, szBuffer, NULL);
err = GetLastError();
printf("\n 2.DevCap.result = %d, err = %d", r, err);
```

In output I see following:

```
1.DevCap.result = -1, err = 0
2.DevCap.result = -1, err = 13
```

Note: Windows error 13 is `ERROR_INVALID_DATA`.

Could you please help me to understand - how to interpret that correcly?
Does that mean that drivers for Epson ink printers do not provide any information on supported print resolutions?
Or is there really some invalid parameters passed? If yes, which one that could be?

Thank you in advance.

PS.
Please note following:

1) Printer and Port names are correct. They are obtaines with `EnumPrinters()` WinAPI call. In this code sample I cut off all irrelevant code, so keep only the functions which fail.

2) The printer itself is working fine, I can print documents and photos to it.

3) Also I have added an "Epson Stylus 300" printer which is configured to use "FILE:" port for printing. And the interesting thing - a call to `DeviceCapabilities(DC_ENUMRESOLUTIONS)` for such printer also reports error# 13. That is why I incline to think that all Epson ink printers do not provide any info on print resolution...

4) All other calls to `DeviceCapabilities()` function (for `DC_PAPERS, DC_PAPERSIZE`, `DC_PAPERNAMES`, etc) works fine for these printers (Epson P50 and Epson Stylus 300). So, printer name and port name are correct, problem exists only for `DeviceCapabilities(DC_ENUMRESOLUTIONS)` call.

Comment: It should be straight forward. Most likely these two printers don't support `DC_ENUMRESOLUTIONS` flag. Install a printer from another company, it will probably work.

Comment: Yes, I know it works for other printers. This software worked for years, only now when I try to print to Epson I got this problem.
I just a little bit puzzled that printer does not provide list of supported resolutions and what that means for me? 
Can I specify resolution=12345 then and expect to see correct printout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does seem to be an error with those Epson printers. However resolution values are device dependent and you shouldn't need it anyway.

You may want to obtain printer resolution through `DEVMODE` and just report it to user:

```
PRINTDLG pdlg = { sizeof PRINTDLG };
pdlg.Flags = PD_RETURNDEFAULT | PD_RETURNDC;
PrintDlg(&pdlg);

DEVMODE* dm = (DEVMODE*)::GlobalLock(pdlg.hDevMode);
cout << "dm->dmDeviceName: " << dm->dmDeviceName << endl;

if (dm->dmFields & DM_PRINTQUALITY)
{
    cout << "dm->dmPrintQuality: " << dm->dmPrintQuality << endl;
}

::GlobalUnlock(pdlg.hDevMode);
```

`dmPrintQuality` is either the printer resolution or one of these device independent values:

```
#define DMRES_DRAFT         (-1)
#define DMRES_LOW           (-2)
#define DMRES_MEDIUM        (-3)
#define DMRES_HIGH          (-4)
```

If user wants to change this value it's better to give access to printer's own setup dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed the problem with an EPSON Stylus Photo RX595 Series.

Barmak Shenmirani is correct that the `dmPrintQuality` field of the `DEVMODE` will indicate one of the negative constants to give a rough idea of the resolution or a positive value in pixels-per-inch for the horizontal resolution.  In the latter case, you can get the vertical resolution from the `dmYResolution` field of the `DEVMODE`.

If you used `EnumPrinters` with level 2 (`PRINTER_INFO_2`) to get the name and port, then you already have a copy of the default `DEVMODE`.

It seems a reasonable heuristic to assume any printer that fails `DC_ENUMRESOLUTIONS` has only one resolution, and it's the resolution in that default `DEVMODE`.  You could try bringing up the print dialog and tweaking the various quality knobs it offers to see if the resolution is different in the resulting `DEVMODE`, but I doubt it'll change.

In the case of my printer, it seems the 360×360 pixels-per-inch resolution reported in the `DEVMODE` is an abstract value since the specs for the printer claim "5760×1440 optimized dpi".  Presumably the driver dithers all those dots to achieve an effective density of 360×360 pixels.

To ensure that this wasn't just a coding error on my part, I also ran it for my laser printer (a Brother) and it reported two resolutions: 600×600 and 300×300.

Comment: I need to know a resolution to re-calculate barcode images to print it in correct size. But as I can see - I can specify almost any resolution - like 300 or 600 - seems it works fine for my Epson P50. Of course it is not a goal to print barcodes all the time on P50, I was only needed some real hardware to test our software. P50 was only the option near me...

Comment: High resolution printers will probably do a good job with a source of any reasonable resolution.